Alpine Kea dhcp server deny unknown-clients
I checked the whole conf file but did not find the option equivalent to "deny unknown-clients" of Debian isc-dhcp-server.
Possible?

Why not just create a pool with enough leases to hold all the known systems & setup reservations?

As by comment of @BobGoddard...
I will create a pool with enough leases to hold all the known systems:
"pools": [ { "pool" : "10.10.10.50 - 10.10.10.55" } ]

i will setup reservations for all:
"reservations": [
  {"hw-address": "1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:1f","ip-address":"192.0.2.50"},
  {"hw-address": "1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:2f","ip-address":"192.0.2.51"},
  {"hw-address": "1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:3f","ip-address":"192.0.2.52"},
  {"hw-address": "1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:4f","ip-address":"192.0.2.53"},
  {"hw-address": "1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:5f","ip-address":"192.0.2.54"},
  {"hw-address": "1a:1b:1c:1d:1e:6f","ip-address":"192.0.2.55"}


Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. - From Review

ok but how can I accept a comment as a solution?

Good point. It may seem unethical, but the standard approach is to write an answer describing the solution, giving credit to the author of the idea (Bob).  Or, of course, you could just [edit] this answer to include the technical content of Bob’s suggestion, perhaps enhancing it with the details of how you did it.  You can then accept the answer.

ok ...i edited my answer but if i insert "@BobGoddard"...not mention him? if i start writing @bob ... doen't appear him username for tag?

Yeah, that looks OK.  Except ‘@’ isn’t really appropriate here; it works only in comments.

I normally upvote answers only when I can verify that they are correct.   I am making an exception and upvoting this one because you took my advice, and because you say the answer works.
